# How to declare array with double brackets

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to make an array this way:

```
var cell = [];    
cell[0][0] = "Förnamn:";    
cell[0][1] = "Efternamn:";    
cell[0][2] = "Telefon:";    
cell[1][1] = "Leitet";    
cell[1][2] = "7716";    
cell[2][0] = "Mats";    
cell[2][1] = "Loock";    
cell[2][2] = "7714";
```

But I get this error:

> Cannot set property '0' of undefined

I have also tried this:

```
var cell = new array[]
```

And get this message:

> Unexpected token ]

And tried this:

```
var cell = new array()
```

But get this error:

> array is not defined

So I need help to declare my variable. It's important that the following works:

```
cell[0][0] = "Förnamn:";
cell[0][1] = "Efternamn:";
cell[0][2] = "Telefon:";
cell[1][0] = "Johan";
cell[1][1] = "Leitet";
cell[1][2] = "7716";
cell[2][0] = "Mats";
cell[2][1] = "Loock";
cell[2][2] = "7714";
```

Comment: The correct way to mark the question as solved is to accept an answer. You can do it after 15 minutes after posting the question (i.e. you can do it already)

Answer (score 5):

```
var a = new Array();
a[0] = new Array();
```

or

```
var a = [[]];
```

Applied to your case:

```
// if you want to be explicit
var cell = [] 
cell[0] = ["Förnamn:", "Efternamn:", "Telefon:"]
cell[1] = ["Johan",    "Leitet",     "7716"    ]
cell[2] = ["Mats",     "Loock",      "7714"    ]

// or
var cell = [
    ["Förnamn:", "Efternamn:", "Telefon:"],
    ["Johan", "Leitet", "7716"],
    ["Mats", "Loock", "7714"]
]
```

Comment: `new Array()` is recommended coding because it can be ... "surprising" at times.

Answer (score 2):

Like this

```
var array = [[]];
```

Literals should be used in JS, not constructors.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to create a literal array is

```
var cell=[
  [
    "Förnamn:",        
    "Efternamn:",
    "Telefon:"
  ],[
    "Johan",
    "Leitet",
    "7716"
  ],[
    "Mats",
    "Loock",
    "7714
  ]
]
```

Then, when you want to add another row, you can do

```
cell.push(["John", "Dvorak", "3455"])
```

---

If you really want to use

```
cell[0][0] = "Förnamn:";    
cell[0][1] = "Efternamn:";    
cell[0][2] = "Telefon:";    
cell[1][1] = "Leitet";    
cell[1][2] = "7716";     
cell[2][0] = "Mats";    
cell[2][1] = "Loock";    
cell[2][2] = "7714";
```

, then do this:

```
var cell=[];
cell[0]=[];
cell[1]=[];
cell[2]=[];

cell[0][0] = "Förnamn:";    
cell[0][1] = "Efternamn:";    
cell[0][2] = "Telefon:";    
cell[1][1] = "Leitet";    
cell[1][2] = "7716";     
cell[2][0] = "Mats";    
cell[2][1] = "Loock";    
cell[2][2] = "7714";
```

or

```
var cell = [];

cell[0] = [];
cell[0][0] = "Förnamn:";    
cell[0][1] = "Efternamn:";    
cell[0][2] = "Telefon:";   
cell[1] = []; 
cell[1][1] = "Leitet";    
cell[1][2] = "7716";  
cell[2] = [];   
cell[2][0] = "Mats";    
cell[2][1] = "Loock";    
cell[2][2] = "7714";
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript does not have 2D arrays in the way that C does. You can kind of emulate it by using an array of arrays, like this:

```
var cell = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  cell[i] = [];
}


cell[0][0] = "Förnamn:";
cell[0][1] = "Efternamn:";
cell[0][2] = "Telefon:";
cell[1][0] = "Johan";
cell[1][1] = "Leitet";
cell[1][2] = "7716";
cell[2][0] = "Mats";
cell[2][1] = "Loock";
cell[2][2] = "7714";
```

After reading your comment, it makes me wonder if your instructor wanted something like this:

```
var cell = [ // The outside array
  [],        // this is cell[0]
  [],        // cell[1]
  []         // cell[2]
];           // and closing the outside array
```

Compressed to one line like this:

```
var cell = [ [], [], [] ];
// or
var cell = [[],[],[]];
```

Or, you can create what we call an object literal and just say what you want...

```
var cell = [
  [
    "Förnamn:",
    "Efternamn:",
    "Telefon:"
  ],
  [
    "Leitet",
    "7716"
  ],
  [
    "Mats",
    "Loock",
    "7714"
  ]
];
```

Comment: Hmm okay. Thank you. Will have to talk to my teachers because in the description of the problem I have to declare it that way :/.

Comment: @Yonnes -- Updated my answer with one other possibility.

Answer (score 0):

```
var cell = [
    [
        "Förnamn:",
        "Efternamn:",
        "Telefon:"
    ],
    [
        "Leitet",
        "7716"
    ],
    [
        "Mats",
        "Loock",
        "7714"
    ]
];
```

Answer (score 0):

In first example, you can make it work like this:

```
var cell = [];    
cell[0] = [];
cell[0][0] = "Förnamn:";    
cell[0][1] = "Efternamn:";    
cell[0][2] = "Telefon:";    
cell[1] = [];
cell[1][1] = "Leitet";    
cell[1][2] = "7716";    
cell[2] = [];
cell[2][0] = "Mats";    
cell[2][1] = "Loock";    
cell[2][2] = "7714";
```

In your code exception is thrown because there is no `cell[0]` - it is undefined, so you must define it first.

Once you are using array constructor, it should be like this:

```
var cell = new Array();
```

And not:

```
var cell = new array[]
```

or

```
var cell = new array();
```

First construction is illegal and second does not works because JS is case sensitive language. But you will have a problem with second level anyway here. Each first level aray must be defined anyway, just like in first code block.